# What version of spring framework can I use with WebSphere 6.1?

Tags: spring-mvc, websphere

Current environment:  WebSphere 6.1 with IBM java jdk 1.5 with Struts 1.3 and some version of Tiles.

I would like to replace Structs 1.3 with Spring MVC.  What is the maximum Spring Framework version can I use?  Fortunately, **JPA 2.0 compatibility is not required** because the current system uses REST calls for all database access instead of using Hibernate.  We will eventually move WebSphere to 8.5, but not anytime time soon.

Again, upto which version of Spring framework can I use with Websphere 6.1 (with IBM jdk 1.5)?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spring with the latest [3.2 version](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.0.html#new-in-3.0-intro).

Comment: Just verified that 3.2.1.RELEASE also runs with WebSphere 6.1; however, WebSphere refused to get along with Tiles 3 and results in "bad major version at offset=6" error.  So I down version Tiles back to 2.2.2 and all is well.  Thanks for your info!

Comment: Tiles 3 must have been compiled with Java 6. WebSphere 6 is only at Java 5

Answer (score 0):

We're using Spring 3.0 today with WebSphere 6.1, and I'm pretty sure there's no reason we can't use 3.1.

Comment: Thanks!  Your answer has led me to get Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE to work with Tiles 2.2.2 under WebSphere 6.1.  Thanks for the hints!  Now that I have a framework going.  I'll give Spring 3.2 and Tiles 3 a try.